# Bootstrap responsiveness aligning to left instead of middle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my html:

```
<div class="gridrow" id="eventsrow">
   <div class="gridcard" id="eventcard" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;margin-bottom:0.5rem;background-color:white">
       <div class="event container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col">
                <span>Test Title</span>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently there is no css for the `gridrow`,`eventsrow`,or `gridcard` and `eventcard` and `event`.

When I look at it on my Samsung Note8 everything looks great (its centered), however when I look at it on my Samsung Galaxy s8 it pushes to the left instead of centering.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you use float left,  this will push your div element to the left and not in the middle. you can try to center your element with 
text-align

```
.gridcard
{
text-align:center;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin-bottom:0.5rem;
background-color:white;
}
```

i hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="gridrow" id="eventsrow">
     <div class="gridcard" id="eventcard" style="float:left; width:100%;height:100%;margin-bottom:0.5rem;background-color:white">
         <div class="event container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-4">
               </div>
               <div class="col-4">
                  <span>Test Title</span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-4">
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

It will divide your entire page in 3 equal columns, then put what you want in the center one. It will work on every device.